Update Drupal from 10.3.9 to 10.4.0 Composer error
I have a website which had multiples updates in the past years without any issue.
Yesterday I tried to update drupal core from 10.3.9 to 10.4.0. Everything is working fine on my local docker, but when I try to deploy to AWS (using elastic beanstalk) I get this error :
...

- Downloading mtdowling/jmespath.php (2.8.0)

- Downloading aws/aws-sdk-php (3.336.0)

- Syncing drupal/s3fs (dev-3.x a08d7b7) into cache

In Git.php line 587:

Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- https://git.drupalcode.org/project/

s3fs.git /root/cache/vcs/https---git.drupalcode.org-project-s3fs.git/

fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/cache/vcs/https---git

.drupalcode.org-project-s3fs.git'

If I revert back to 10.3.9 I don't have this issue anymore so I guess there is some update here that prevent s3fs module to sync but I cant' find out what.
I also tried to remove the vendor folder and composer.lock but with no luck.
Trying to mkdir a /root/cache folder or to chmod it in .ebextension file doesn't change anything either.
Any idea what I could try to do?
Thank you

What does "when I try to deploy" mean? Usually, Composer can't deploy anything

As mentioned in my post I indicate when I try to deploy to AWS elastic Beanstalk. I use gitlab-ci and AWS CLI to deploy my project to elastic beanstalk (what I have been doing for years), and this is working correctly. But when updating from 10.3.9 to 10.4.0 I face this composer error. It isn't directly related to drupal (meaning it's not an error with the drupal code), but is is related in a way with this update since when I roll back to previous version I don't have this error anymore. What about this downvote? I explained correctly and with details what my issue was... This is a nonsense

This is an error from git. Usually this is caused by a permission issue. The cause of the error should be mentioned at the end of the message, ie. "fatal: could not create leading directories of '<path/to/project.git>': ", where the  could be "Permission denied", "Read-only file system", etc.
